# Question about counting measure.

Tags: measure-theory

A set function $c$ defined on all of $\mathbb R$, is defined as follows. Define $c(E)$ to be infinity if $E$ has infinitely many members and $c(E)$ to be equal to the number of elements in $E$ if $E$ is finite; define $c(\varnothing)=0$. Show that $c$ is a countably additive and translation invariant set function. This set function is called the counting measure.

To prove this question, I must prove:

- Countably Additive for two cases: infinite and finite.
- Translation Invariant for two cases: infinite and finite.

Let $E$ is infinite set.

Countably Additive: We must prove:

\begin{align}
c\left( \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n
\end{align}

Now I try to prove
\begin{align}
c\left( \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right) = c(E_1\cup E_2\cup \ldots)=\infty=\infty+\infty+\ldots=c(E_1)+c(E_2)+\ldots = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty E_n
\end{align}

Translation Invariant, we must prove:
If $E\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)$  and $E+x=\{x+y\mid y\in E\}$ then $c(E)=c(E+x)$.

Since $E$ is infinity then $c(E)=\infty$. Since $E$ is infinity, the set $E+x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ is also infinite set. Then, $c(E+x)=\infty$. So, $c(E)=c(E+x)$.

For the same way, finite case is similar.

I'm not sure with my effort. Is the prove above is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof of countable additivity is wrong. You said 'Let $E$ is infinite set' and proved something that does not involve $E$.

Suppose $E_i$ are disjoint and $\bigcup_n E_i$ is a finite set . Then each $E_i$ is a finite set and, in fact, $E_i$ is empty for $i$ sufficiently large. Now $c(\bigcup_n E_i) =\sum_i c(E_i)$ is clear.

If $\bigcup_n E_i$ is an infinite set we have to show that $\sum_i c(E_i)=\infty$. Prove this by contradiction. Suppose  $\sum_i c(E_i)<\infty$. Then $c(E_i) \to 0$ which implies that $E_i$ is empty for $i$ sufficiently large and each $E_i$ is a finite set. Do you see the contradiction now?

Comment: Why $E_i$ is empty if $i$ sufficiently large?

Comment: Also, why if $\sum\limits_{i} c(E_i)<\infty$ then $c(E_i)\to 0$?

Comment: 1) If each $E_i$ is non-empty then there will be infinitely many elements in their union (because the sets are disjoint). 2)  It is a basic fact from Calculus that if a series $\sum a_n$ is convergent the the general term $a_n \to 0$.  @OngkyDennyWijaya